# How to insert a UISegementedControl to a navigationBar, and can change title size, like the apple connect app?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

the 1 is the big title
the 2 is normal title

How to insert a UISegementedControl to a navigationBar like this

Comment: https://tva1.sinaimg.cn/large/008eGmZEgy1gnwfftl2htj30mf0mzdk2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can set your navigation bar with an array like that

```
 let titles = ["first", "Second"]
segmentControl = UISegmentedControl(items: titles)
segmentControl.tintColor = UIColor.white
segmentControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
for index in 0...titles.count-1 {
    segmentControl.setWidth(120, forSegmentAt: index)
}
segmentControl.sizeToFit()
segmentControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(segmentChanged), for: .valueChanged)
segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
segmentControl.sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
navigationItem.titleView = segmentControl
```